# Possible case of MBD in a leopard gecko

Tags: health, reptiles, diseases, leopard-geckos

My 8 month old leopard gecko has had his front left leg turned inwards for the past 2 weeks. He also stays in his hide a lot and rarely comes out. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently caring for a leopard gecko with MBD. I'd suggest taking him to the vet and increasing the calcium in his diet.